# Sharing example tables between scenarios

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow

I have a feature file with 3 scenarios for doing some BDD tests on a C# project. Each scenario is demonstrated using a large examples table (about 40 rows). Example tables are the same. Here how the feature file looks like:

```
Scenario Outline: scenario1
 <stmt set 1>
 Examples:
 <LargeTable>

Scenario Outline: scenario2
 <stmt set 2>
 Examples:
 <LargeTable>

Scenario Outline: scenario3
 <stmt set 3>
 Examples:
 <LargeTable>
```

I do not like repeating the same examples for each scenario. Is there a way to write the example table once and make scenarios reference it, i.e. something like this:

```
Scenario Outline: scenario1
 <stmt set 1>
 Examples:
 <ref LargeTable>

Scenario Outline: scenario2
 <stmt set 2>
 Examples:
 <ref LargeTable>

Scenario Outline: scenario3
 <stmt set 3>
 Examples:
 <ref LargeTable>

LargeTable:
<bla>
```

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SpecFlow's "background" keyword.

```
Background: 
    Given my table looks like
    | .... | .... |
```

Put this before your scenarios. You can then include the table as you would for any other Given, and it will be available for every scenario in the file.

Comment: Seems to solve the problem, but is it a good practice to do so? keep in mind that my example table is about 40 rows? Thanks.

Comment: Regarding good practices for using Background: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Background

Comment: Do whatever helps to call out the difference between the scenarios, and between different sets of contexts. If there's only a couple of rows in the table which are important to the outcomes in the scenarios, consider adding just those rows to the file and setting up the rest of the table silently, in the background, or with a step like "And forty other customers" (or whatever your data represents).  Helping to draw attention to the different contexts will help the scenarios be easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 4):

No, SpecFlow does not support this. 
See http://dannorth.net/2008/06/30/let-your-examples-flow/ for some clues as to why the feature is not implemented in BDD frameworks.

Comment: +1 for this answer. @H.Josef, whilst you could use Lunivore's approach to achieve what you want, that approach is considered an anti-pattern (see North's article).

Comment: But a situation like this can occur and there should a solution, in my case the example table **is** the specification. i.e. it lists precisely how elements of domain (A) should be mapped to elements of domain (B). scenarios describe more complex interactions based on this mapping. Therefor I must replicate the example table for each scenario.

Comment: In this article Dan was referring particularly to people setting up mocks in re-used methods, etc., when the set-up was actually relevant to the outcome - hiding the "magic". If your context is relevant to the particular outcome of the scenario, do include it. If it's just realistic background data, don't. Also remember that Dan said, *flow trumps DRY*. That doesn't mean DRY is bad; it just means don't compromise readability to get it. Particularly, it's OK to get stuff out of the way if it makes your scenarios *more* readable. Look at the principles he's putting forward here and follow those.

Comment: BTW, SpecFlow, Cucumber and JBehave all support this (using Background, Background and Before keywords respectively). It's common for some scenarios to have a lot of realistic default data which is relevant for ensuring correct behaviour but not relevant for describing it (which you absolutely wouldn't hide, as per Dan's article). This is a good solution for the default, non-descriptive steps.