# Specflow "master" table or table data share options

Tags: c#, .net, bdd, specflow

I am currently working with Specflow with c#. 
I have two feature files with the exact same table/data in the background. 
Also within both feature files, I have scenarios which cannot be merged into one feature file (they need to remain in two separate files).

Now, what I am trying to do is extract the background table from both classes and put it in it's own class in order to keep from having to edit/keep track of two different tables (they are fairly large) .

Is there a way that I can reference just a background from two different feature files as if the feature files had the background themselves?

Thanks!

---

EDIT: Currently, I have the following

```
           FEATURE_1                               FEATURE_2
           |                                       |    
           BackgroundTable                         Same BackgroundTable
           |                                       |
           Scenario_1                              Different_Scenario_1

           Scenario_2                              Different_Scenario_2
           .                                       .
           .                                       .
```

### .                                       .

```
I want to change it so that I can have


                      FEATURE_WITH_ONLY_MASTER_BACKGROUND
                      |
                      BackgroundMasterTable
                      .
                      .

           FEATURE_1                               FEATURE_2
           |                                       |    
           ReferenceToMasterTable                  ReferenceToMasterTable
           |                                       |
           Scenario_1                              Different_Scenario_1

           Scenario_2                              Different_Scenario_2
           .                                       .
           .                                       .
           .                                       .
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharing example tables between scenarios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23385843/sharing-example-tables-between-scenarios)

Comment: This is not a duplicate because I don't just need to use a background, I need to share that background between two different feature files and be able to run them independently.

Comment: Ok, my mistake. I've retracted the close flag.

Comment: Having fairly large table in the Background section is bad practice. Regarding good practices for using Background: github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method for this is to use a BeforeFeature hook to call your Given..() step to set up your background table and save it to FeatureContext.Current, and then apply that hook via an attribute to each of the features that need that table.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful for my knowledge. However I have decide to switch to a different method of sharing data within my feature files.